# Check if website is up / down using php websockets

Tags: php, websocket, phpwebsocket

I am trying to create a monitoring tool using `php`, which would check if a website is up / down in intervals of 5 minutes. I would like to use web-sockets for this, as I am new to the concept of web-sockets, I could only find communicating with web-sockets using `php` and `javascript` but I need server to server socket communication using `php web-sockets`. Can someone help me in this.

P.S. : I chose to use web-sockets because I could be monitoring 30+ websites hosted in a single server. I tried using curl/ping, but had to leave it as they would make my server heavy as the requests would be flooding.

Comment: why would you not use one of the free solutions out there that do this for you? https://uptimerobot.com/ for example.

Comment: I am trying to develop my own application and I cannot use curl/ping which  uptimerobot.com could be using as it will mess with the analytics of my server and also make it flooded with requests